# Sorting bash arguments

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following lines:

```
Is,C0Cf[0],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C1Cf[0],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C0Cf[1],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C1Cf[1],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
     .
     .
     .
```

how to sort it according to the second column where first all C0Cf[0]...C0Cf[50] then the C1Cf.. ?

Comment: [Sorting file by second column](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144758/sorting-file-by-second-column)

Comment: How is supposed to be sorted? C0Cf is it to be sorted in ascii order? the index inside `[1]` is an integer, rigth? Please edit the question an add a longer abstract with bigger indexes and also add an output result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have many answers to this on the net. And also this is not a programming question its just a linux question.

Comment: can a line contain `C32Cf[0]` ? or `C0Cf[03]`? Could you edit the question an provide more lines and also an example of the sorted output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sort -n -k 2 -t, inputfile.txt
```

For example:

```
$ cat inputfile.txt
Is,C0Cf[0],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C1Cf[0],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C0Cf[1],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C1Cf[1],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
$ sort -k 2 -t, inputfile.txt
Is,C0Cf[0],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C0Cf[1],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C1Cf[0],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
Is,C1Cf[1],0x0,LutValue,0,11,0x0
$
```

`-k 2` sorts by the second field. `-t,` makes `,` the field separator. `-n` sorts by numeric value.

Comment: I think it won't work with lines containing C0Cf[15], right?

Comment: Fixed, add `-n` to `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort alphabetically first on the second column, then split the column into two columns and do secondary sort on the number in square brackets.

```
sed 's/\[/,/' input-file \
| sort -t, -k2,2 -k3,3n \
| sed 's/\(,[^,]*\),/\1[/'
```

If the input can contain strings like C10Cf, you need to replace the first C as well, and make the primary sorting numeric:

```
sed 's/,C/,/;s/\[/,/' input-file \
| sort -t, -k2,2n -k3,3n \
| sed 's/,\([^,]*\),/,C\1[/'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` has command line parameters to allow you to do this:
`-t` specifies the separator,
`-k` specifies the field to sort on

So you can use `sort -t',' -k2`, although I have to admit I've not tried it!